# Spring @Bean alternative to @EnableJpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a library that declares some repositories that are autodiscovered with EnableJpaRepository.

Then I have a project that include the library and that declares some repos that are **extending** those from the library.

The new repos are autodiscovered as well with EnableJpaRepository.

The problem is that when the app starts, both the base and the derived repositories are discovered and spring doesn't like it :)

So I'm looking for a way to manually declare the repositories in a configuration like.

```
class PersistenceConfig {
@Bean
public Repo getMyRepo(){
 return new RepoImpl();
}
```

The same thing that we do for Services or Components
But it's not possible since the implementation is not existing and it's generated by spring.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? What's the result?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev,  it's not possible to declare the bean since the implementation is not existing (it's generated by spring). So I don't know what to put into the method that creates the bean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly perform an override, the derived bean must have the same name of the base bean.
So, if using component scan the classes must have the same name or if using configuration, the get methods for the beans must have the same name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use for your repositories a package that differs from the one in library. And  tell Spring JPA to scan only your packages for repository classes. Like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mydomain.jpa.myrepository")
```

Comment: that's not what I asked and it doens't solve the problem...